# sockets and ARP (IP neighbor) table entries

Tags: linux, sockets, arp

On CentOS 6.4 (kernel 2.6.32), why does the second *arping* invocation below create a new ARP table entry, but the first does not?  The network behavior is identical, and my confusion is that, to my eye, *the syscalls are practically equivalent*.  What system behavior am I missing here?

```
#:- arping -s 10.0.2.15 -f 10.0.2.4
ARPING 10.0.2.4 from 10.0.2.15 eth0
Unicast reply from 10.0.2.4 [52:54:00:01:02:03]  0.681ms
Sent 1 probes (1 broadcast(s))
Received 1 response(s)
#:- ip neigh show | grep -c '^10\.0\.2\.4 '
0                                                   # <--- no new ARP entry

#:- arping -f 10.0.2.4
ARPING 10.0.2.4 from 10.0.2.15 eth0
Unicast reply from 10.0.2.4 [52:54:00:01:02:03]  0.681ms
Sent 1 probes (1 broadcast(s))
Received 1 response(s)
#:- ip neigh show | grep -c '^10\.0\.2\.4 '
1                                                   # <--- new ARP entry
```

10.0.2.15 is the address of eth0 in the above.  If you try to reproduce this yourself, be careful that your target is not in the ARP table at all — e.g., it cannot be in a STALE state, it must be entirely absent.

Now, if I *strace* each invocation (and ignore differences in memory locations) the relevant diff is this:

```
$:- diff -uN /tmp/arp-no.trace /tmp/arp-yes.trace
--- /tmp/arp-no.trace   2014-04-23 20:17:46.301575314 -0500
+++ /tmp/arp-yes.trace  2014-04-23 20:17:48.790575314 -0500
@@ -1,4 +1,4 @@
-execve("/sbin/arping", ["arping", "-s", "10.0.2.15", "-f", "10.0.2.4"], [/* 19 vars */]) = 0
+execve("/sbin/arping", ["arping", "-f", "10.0.2.4"], [/* 19 vars */]) = 0
 brk(0)                                  = 0xMEMLOCATION
 mmap(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0xMEMLOCATION
 access("/etc/ld.so.preload", R_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
@@ -37,7 +37,9 @@
 ioctl(3, SIOCGIFFLAGS, {ifr_name="eth0", ifr_flags=IFF_UP|IFF_BROADCAST|IFF_RUNNING|IFF_MULTICAST}) = 0
 socket(PF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, IPPROTO_IP) = 4
 setsockopt(4, SOL_SOCKET, SO_BINDTODEVICE, "eth0\0", 5) = 0
-bind(4, {sa_family=AF_INET, sin_port=htons(0), sin_addr=inet_addr("10.0.2.15")}, 16) = 0
+setsockopt(4, SOL_SOCKET, SO_DONTROUTE, [1], 4) = 0
+connect(4, {sa_family=AF_INET, sin_port=htons(1025), sin_addr=inet_addr("10.0.2.4")}, 16) = 0
+getsockname(4, {sa_family=AF_INET, sin_port=htons(38207), sin_addr=inet_addr("10.0.2.15")}, [16]) = 0
 close(4)                                = 0
 bind(3, {sa_family=AF_PACKET, proto=0x806, if2, pkttype=PACKET_HOST, addr(0)={0, }, 40) = 0
 getsockname(3, {sa_family=AF_PACKET, proto=0x806, if2, pkttype=PACKET_HOST, addr(6)={1, 080027538173}, [18]) = 0
 ... and then the sendto/recvfrom happen ...
```

In the case where I specify the source IP and no ARP entry is created, the source IP address is validated with a short-lived IPPROTO_IP socket created, bound, and **closed**.  In the second case, *arping* guesses the source IP address with a short-lived IPPROTO_IP socket created, connect()ed, getsockname()d, and **closed**.

After that, the program behavior (and network activity) is identical.  However, the system reaction is not, and the only material difference I see is each program's different but innocuous use of a now-closed socket.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's curious, isn't it? :-)

I'm pretty sure it's the same kernel bug/feature I investigated in another Arping implementation (mine):

https://blog.habets.se/2012/10/Interesting-Arping-bug-report

No point cut-and-pasting the long explanation, but in short: If you look up a route and then send a raw ARP packet, then the kernel will for some reason sniff the ARP reply and populate the ARP table.

I have no idea why, or if it's even intended behaviour. But it is the kernel that does it.